# Is there a way to pass dependencies to JPA converters?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a custom converter that needs to use few dependencies.

Since converters are managed by JPA, I can't figure out a way of passing it dependencies from another component (like dependency injector). Is there such a way?

```
@Converter
public class CompressingJsonConverter implements AttributeConverter<CompressedJson, Byte[]> {

    private final Compressing compressing;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public CompressingJsonConverter() {
        // I would like to inject those dependencies instead
        compressing = new Compressing();
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using a static field. Either your DI framework supports static injections (I know Guice and Salta do), or you have to do it by hand during startup. Consider registering the Injector (Guice, Salta) or an Instance (JavaEE/CDI) in a utility class and using it from wherever you need.

Answer (score -1):

This depends on which world are your two objects living :

- If both are created by CID then there should not have been any issues just using javax.inject would suffice.
- If one is created by a different DI framework say GUICE then you need to write some glue code to connect them.

One such technique I used in one of my projects is to create a class like :

```html
// create a new class
class Bridge { @Inject public static ObjectMapper objectMapper; }

// in GUICE module 
requestStaticInjection(Bridge.class)

// in Convertor 
class MyConvertor {

  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  public MyConvertor(){
    this.objectMapper = Bridge.objectMapper;
  }
}
```